# check if a list of array contains an array in c#

Tags: c#, equality

I'm working in c# and I have a list of integer arrays and an array. I need to check if the list contains that specific array. The list.Contains(T item) method didn't provide the desired output, so I wrote a custom method

```
static bool CheckContains( List<int[]> forbiddenChoice, int[] finalChoice)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < forbiddenChoice.Count; i++)
        {
            if(Array.Equals(forbiddenChoice[i], finalChoice))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

still, this method always returns false even if I pass an array that is included in the list.
How to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you detail the possible values and their expected result?

Comment: What is your definition of equality?

Comment: FWIW I [can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bgrtRS).

Comment: Your `Array.Equals()` is really calling `object.Equals()` which (for an array) will compare REFERENCES, not contents. Try `forbiddenChoice[i].SequenceEquals(finalChoice)`

Comment: So equality means "same items in same order"?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay in this case, I'm just checking if both of the arrays have the same elements in the same order, so it's the same item in the same order.  consider the

Comment: In that case @MatthewWatson has the correct suggestion.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It worked with 'forbiddenChoice[i].SequenceEqual(finalChoice)' method. Thanks a lot

Comment: You could also use LINQ for this: `forbiddenChoice.Any(choice => choice.SequenceEqual(finalChoice))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SequenceEqual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=net-6.0) method from `System.Linq`

```
static bool CheckContains(List<int[]> forbiddenChoice, int[] finalChoice)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < forbiddenChoice.Count; i++)
    {
        if (forbiddenChoice[i].SequenceEqual(finalChoice))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

```
if (forbiddenChoice[i].SequenceEqual( finalChoice))
{
    return true;
}
```

Array.IsEqual would return true just if both variables refer to the same object:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 4, 5 };
int[] array5 = { 1, 4, 5 };
bool test02 = array5.Equals(array1); // returns False
array5 = array1;
test02 = array5.Equals(array1); // returns True
```